# Bootstrap <span> align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code and want to align `Text 2` to the center of the footer.

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <span style="float:left;">
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span style="float:right;">
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```

`Text 1` and `Text 3` are fine. But I don't get `Text 2` to the center

Comment: Use <p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>

Comment: Any specific reason you are floating spans around yourself - instead of using bootstrap columns …?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-footer text-center">
    <span class="pull-left">
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span >
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```

Or you can use `flexbox`

```css
.panel-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-footer">
  <span>
        Text 1
    </span>
  <span>
        Text 2
    </span>
  <span>
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following options

```
<div class="panel-footer text-center">
    <span style="float:left;">
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block;text-align: center">
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span style="float:right;">
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <span>
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span>
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span>
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>


.panel-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox:

```
.panel-footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use **only Bootstrap classes** if possible. In this case you can achieve it by adding `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes instead of inline floats in first and last `<span>`, and adding `text-center` class to your wrapping `<div>` element. That way you also don't need any inline CSS for middle `<span>`.

The full working code will look like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-footer text-center">
    <span class="pull-left">
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span>
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```

Check Bootsrap documentation about [Quick floats](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) and [Alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) for more information about using pull and text classes

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-between;` with `flexbox`

```css
.panel-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
  <span>Text 1</span>
  <span>Text 2</span>
  <span>Text 3</span>
</div>
```

or you can simply use bootstrap grid and few classes.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-xs-4">Text 1</span>
    <span class="col-xs-4 text-center">Text 2</span>
    <span class="col-xs-4 text-right">Text 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```css
.panel-footer span{
  width: calc(100%/3);
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-footer span:first-child{
  text-align: left;
}

.panel-footer span:last-child{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
    <span>
        Text 1
    </span>
    <span>
        Text 2
    </span>
    <span>
        Text 3
    </span>
</div>
```